# Laravel Redirect Me to /Home Link When Clicking on the Reset Password Link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get Forgot Password functionality in my web app, so i am using laravel for this. When i click on the forgot password it shows me the a form that takes email on which i need to reset password when i click on the reset password button it sends a mail on the linked id, and when i click on the link in the mail it redirect me to the change password page that has password and confirm password field when i click on the reset password it redirects me to home link.

**The issue is "first time it changes my password successfully", but when i tried for another account to reset password, when clicking on the link on the mail it redirects me to home other than the password change form and it happens for the all account now.**

*What is the problem that causes the above issue please explain and how to resolve this issue*

Here is my password reset routes:

```
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
```

Here is the ResetsPasswords.php class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
use RedirectsUsers;

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
  }

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this- 
 >validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful 
     we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation error messages.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function validationErrorMessages()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $password
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}

/**
 * Get the response for a successful password reset.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetResponse($response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                        ->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for a failed password reset.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker();
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
}
```

and Here is the SendsResetEmails.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
 {
/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('auth.passwords.email');
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have 
   attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Validate the email for the given request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
}

/**
 * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
{
    return back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return back()->withErrors(
        ['email' => trans($response)]
    );
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
 */
public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker();
}
}
```

Comment: please explain. what you exactly want?

Comment: The question is still unclear. We need you to clarify what you are trying to do and what is happening instead. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mike sir Now I have completely explain my issue. Please help to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice the in the `ResetPasswordController` we have:

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

After the password is reset, it logs the user in. However, we are also using the `guest` middleware in the same class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

Therefore if you try to visit the password reset page while logged in, you will be redirected. So just log out first.